# How to fix ViewController does not conform to ViewControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, xcode6, uistoryboardsegue

I have a CoreData project where I've got a **FilterViewController** set up and I want to display the results in a **DisplayResultsViewController**.

I know it's something to do with the delegate, but I'm stumped how to fix it. I know I'm not the first person to move data from one VC to another, but I can't figure out the answer.

```
// Top of FilterViewController
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func filterViewController(filter: FilterViewController,
        didSelectPredicate predicate:NSPredicate?,
        sortDescriptor:NSSortDescriptor?)
}

// Predicates set here
// IBAction to trigger the segue
@IBAction func filter(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    delegate!.filterViewController(self,
        didSelectPredicate: selectedPredicate,
        sortDescriptor: selectedSortDescriptor)

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toDisplaySearchResults" {

        let navController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
        let filterVC = navController.topViewController as StretchSelectorViewController


        filterVC.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
        filterVC.delegate = self // **ERROR here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the code that declares the class containing the method that fails (and thus determines what `self` is) so we're missing the key line of code. But in general, your view controller should be declared something like:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerDelegate {
    ....
}
```

... where the first class after the colon (`UIViewController`) indicates the superclass and the following subsequent items(s) identify protocols to which your class is declaring conformance. The error indicates that your class doesn't conform to the ViewControllerDelegate protocol, so it must be missing that declaration.

Comment: Regarding the 'protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate: class' line, I've read elsewhere it's good practice to add 'class' after the delegate and put the protocol line at the top.

What needs to happen in the destinationVC to take all the info from the filterVC?

Comment: Okay, I see it's a [Class-only Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_422). You learn something new every day! To pass info between VC's, you'd typically have the source set a member variable on the destination. If there is a lot of data to be transferred, you can simply have the source identify itself to the dest, and then have the dest "pull" the data from the source.